# use of proc autoreg to estimate parameters for ARIMA-GARCH model in sas

Tags: time-series, arima, sas, garch

I have fitted my data to a seasonal ARIMA model. Now I want to analyze the variance of the time series data. I learned from sas tutorial to use proc autoreg, and model statement. However, the model in the example is simple regression model on time only (model y=time). For my case, I have an arima model, how should I make the model statement, more specifically for the Moving Average error terms in my model.

Comment: I don't know how to do it in SAS, but you should have a two-equation model: the conditional mean of the process is described by ARIMA, while the conditional variance of the errors in the ARIMA model is described by a GARCH model. The two equations would have to be estimated simultaneously. I hope there is some procedure allowing to specify and estimate an ARIMA-GARCH model in SAS (at least there are similar procedures in R, Stata and some other statistical packages).

Comment: May I know what is your objective and can you share me your dataset to have a view? you may need to know which Garch model you need to use and I think I can guide you slowly how to do it step by step. Thanks.
Wan